# Socket.io lado frontend no es reconocido (la libreria)

Tags: javascript, npm, socket.io

estoy instalando la lib de socket de js para el front: `socket.io-client`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo he instalado con **npm** .

Pero he intentado instanciarlo de mil maneras en mi js de la pagina y siempre da error.

```
//Paquetes npm
const socket = require('socket.io-client');
//..mas codigo..
//..mas codigo..
//..mas codigo..
//..mas codigo..
//..mas codigo..
```

Estoy usando js vanilla pero le he puesto npm par gestionar menor las posibles dependencias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el error es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es porque en el lado del cliente no se importa como en el lado del servidor, debes agregar la libreria js de socket.io y luego llamarla `var socket = io('Tu URL del Servidor', { transport: ['websocket'] });` te dejo la [documentacion](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/) para que indagues mas

Comment: @TheVicShow Gracias por contestar, he cambiado la forma en la que lo importo pero me dice que **io** no esta definido :(

Comment: Eso sucede porque no has importado la librería `<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.4.1/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-fKnu0iswBIqkjxrhQCTZ7qlLHOFEgNkRmK2vaO/LbTZSXdJfAu6ewRBdwHPhBo/H" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` agrégala en tu HTML principal, recuerda que la llamada de archivos js es en cascada, por lo que debes agregar el js de socket IO antes de tu archivo JS donde haces el llamado al IO

Comment: Y cual seria la alternativa al CDN, es decir, instalar el binario de la lib en mi pc. ( es lo que pretendia con el npm que mencione en la pregunta, no me gusta los CDN)

Comment: Puedes meter la URL `https://cdn.socket.io/4.4.1/socket.io.min.js` del CDN en el navegador y copiar todo el JS que te aparecerá y ponerla en un archivo que crees tú!